# Combinations And Mass Set Intersections With Apache Spark (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**The Challenge:**
The data is an RDD in the shape of [(u, p), (u, p), ...] where u and p are both strings. My challenging desired output is [((p,p), u), ..] where the key in each element is a combination of all p's that share a u.

**Already Tried:**

1. Using cartesian and filter to simulate combination.
2. Tried to use itertools.combinations in Python for each element and then flatMap, like something like this:`[(tuple(sorted(e)), x[0]) for e in combinations(x[1].split(','),2)])`

The problem with what I already tried is that the executor nodes seem to go down, presumably from memory consumption.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here's some more info and background for the question:

I'm looking to find the overlap count/cardinality of the intersection for every two "p"s where a "p" is a collection id and "u" is a member of a collection.

The input is a huge list of records of relationships between a "p" and a "u", which can be for example: 
`[(u1,p1), (u2, p2), (u1, p2), (u2, p1), (u1, p3)]`

The desired output is: `[((p1,p2), 2), ((p1, p3), 1), ((p2, p3), 1)]` 
(note combinations and not permutations)

A few more details about the input data:

1. There are 50k - 100k different "p"s.
2. A "p" can have a few hundred million unique "u"s.
3. There can be duplicate rows of input data. In other words multiple instances of `(u,p)` but that doesn't change the problem when it comes to treating the list of "u"s as a set for a given "p" for the intersection step.

As for hardware, I'm using about 41 m3.xlarges on EMR (Spark 1.3.1 on Yarn) and kicking the shell off this way:
`./pyspark --master yarn-client --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 3G --num-executors 160`

Comment: Please edit your question to include your exact goals (the one you've described in the comments), example input and expected output. Some details about amount of data, statistics (average number of distinct p's per u) and configuration could be useful as well.

Comment: Sure, i've made the requested updates. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify - a single p can have _a few hundred million unique "u"s_? Also, do you need an exact solution or is an approximation acceptable?

Comment: _a single p can have a few hundred million unique "u"s_ - that is to say the collection "p" can have up to a few hundred million unique members in that collection (each member of the collection/set is denoted by "u"). I'm looking for an exact solution. I already have an exact solution that works on one machine, but I'm starting to outgrow it and would like to distribute it to make it scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourRdd.groupByKey().map(lambda (a,b): (b,a))
```

The group by key will aggregate all the values of "u" into

```
[(u1,(p1,p2,p3..,px)),(ux,(p1,...,px))]
```

The map will swap the keys and the values, this should give the desired output.  groupByKey spills to disk when not enough memory is available, so this should alleviate your potential memory consumption issue as well.

//EDIT based on the new information.

I can't provide an exact answer, but I can help walk you through a way that should work with most of the code:

Once you do the groupByKey, the data is partitioned such that every instance of a single key is on the same machine.  Now that we know all the "p's" for a single "u" are on the same machine, we can start manipulating the values.

Lets take my initial code as a starting point, but modify it a bit.

```
rdd_1 = yourRdd.groupByKey()
rdd_2 = rdd1.mapValues(mapFunction).flatMapValues()
```

The mapFunction is where the magic will happen.  The function will take a tuple input of all the values of p, and then output a list of tuples where each tuple is a pair of p values.

```
#Updated based on Zero's recommendation of generators.
def mapFunction(tple):
    l = list(tple)
    for i in range(len(tple))
        for j in l[i+1:]
             yield (l[i], j)
```

You'll need to add something to handle when you get to the i=len(tple) so we don't an out of bounds exception.  You still might run into memory issues, but the next part should help you on that.

I think we can mess with your executor configurations.  Given your machine set up, I think we can create much LARGER executors.  In addition your application isn't caching data that I'm aware of, so we can set all of the executor memory to be used for objects my modifying the memoryFraction setting.  I've found a few bigger executors are better than a many smaller executors  (though running with YARN, its tougher to get large amount of resources all the time, but thats a whole different conversation).  Try to use executors between 16 and 32gb, with 2-5 cores.

I would do a spark sumbit similar to this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 16g --num-executors 30 --executor-cores 4  --conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0
```

Skip the memoryFraction setting if you are caching/persisting data anywhere

Comment: I suppose you could do a reduceByKey as suggested by @Paul and build an array of values for each key.  The only way to minimize shuffling of data, is to reduce the data somehow.  A reduceByKey in general is much, much more efficient than a group by key, as a reduce happens locally first, then the data from the initial reduce is shuffled.  I'm not sure how big your set of data for the p's are, so you could run into a memory issue there.

Comment: The counting is clear to me with reduceByKey, however the real issue is getting the combination of every pair of "p"s that share a "u" as a key. Therefore each element in the result should be ((p,p), u). The idea is that I can count on that RDD to get the number of relationships/intersections between any two "p"s

Comment: So would a valid example be:

(p,u)
input data : (1,2), (3,2), (2,2); and the desired output: ((1,3),2), ((1,2),2), ((3,2),2) ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The idea is then I can then count each results and thereby do set intersections in mass. I've updated the question too better illustrate the challenge. I really appreciate the help and please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Comment: I think we can get it done with one shuffle.  If we make heave use of mapValues/flatMapValues, then after the initial shuffling, everything can be done locally.  I'll go over my strategy, by editing my answer.

Comment: I would use itertools combinations or generator instead of creating a list `mapFunction`.

Comment: Based on a lot of your configuration I was able to get through the groupByKey without a hitch. I saw your comment about Yarn not being ideal for memory intensive things, so I 1) switched to using the spark ec2 scripts so I can use the standalone mode (2) upgraded to newest version 1.5.2 (3) got fewer larger nodes and maximized memory per executor to reduce shuffle. The configuration seems much simpler when not having to think about Yarn containers as well and wondering how that affects performance. Thanks so much for both your help guys

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to move computations to a `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

rdd = ...
df = rdd.toDF(["u", "p"])

xs = df.alias("xs")
ys = df.alias("ys")

result = (xs
    .join(ys, (col("xs.u") == col("ys.u")) & (col("xs.p") < col("ys.p")))
    .groupBy(col("xs.p"), col("ys.p"))
    .count())
```

I am not particularly optimistic though. If you want an exact answer then one way or another data has to be shuffled.

Comment: I agree that data will have to be shuffled atleast once, unless the data is stored somewhere with partitioning set on the values of u